# Calling MPI_Wtime result in abnormal exit of thread

Tags: c, mpi

When I tried to measure the elasped time of this program, I called MPI_Wtime() twice.

```
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

commT_S=MPI_Wtick();

MPI_Bcast(a, n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(b, n, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(x, n, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&distri, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&leftover, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (id <= leftover & id !=0)
{
    distri++;
    left=0;
}
if (id!=root){
    for (int i = 0; i < distri; i++)
    {
        int cur_i;
        cur_i = (id-1)*distri+left*leftover+i;
        double inv;
        inv = 1.0 / a[cur_i*n+cur_i] ;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            
            if (cur_i==j)
            {
                my_iter_vec[i*(n+1)+j] = 0.0;
                continue;
            }
            my_iter_vec[i*(n+1)+j] = -a[cur_i*n+j]*inv; //i row j column
        }
        my_iter_vec[i*(n+1)+n]= b[cur_i]*inv;//constant term
        
    }
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
commT_E=MPI_Wtick();
```

But Then I get an error message like this.

```
job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0-1] terminated

[2] process exited without calling finalize

[3] terminated

---- error analysis -----

[2] on MSI
jacob_P2 ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000374
```

I think it has something to do with this loop:

```
if (id!=root){
        for (int i = 0; i < distri; i++)
        {
            int cur_i;
            cur_i = (id-1)*distri+left*leftover+i;
            double inv;
            inv = 1.0 / a[cur_i*n+cur_i] ;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                
                if (cur_i==j)
                {
                    my_iter_vec[i*(n+1)+j] = 0.0;
                    continue;
                }
                my_iter_vec[i*(n+1)+j] = -a[cur_i*n+j]*inv; //i row j column
            }
            my_iter_vec[i*(n+1)+n]= b[cur_i]*inv;//constant term
            
        }
    }
```

When I add this loop to the program, this issue shows up. When this loop is removed, I can call MPI_Wtime() twice without ant error.

This program works just fine when I call MPI_Wtime only once or without calling this method.

What should I do to measure the passed time of this program?

The entire program is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <omp.h>
// #include <math.h>


/* matrix-vector multiply : y = A * x */
void MatVec(int n, double *a, double *x, double *y) {
  int i, j;
   
  for (i=0; i< n; i++) {
    double t = 0.0;
    for (j=0; j<= n; j++){
    t += a[i*n+j] * x[j];
    }
    y[i] = t;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    // Get my rank in the communicator
    int size,id;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    // Determine the rank of the broadcast emitter process
    int root = 0;
    int n;
    n=7;
    if (size<=1)
    {
        printf("this code is not designed for current thread number:%d\n",size);
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }
    double commT_S,commT_E,compT_S,compT_E;
    double commT = 0.0;
    double compT = 0.0;
    /*   Memory assignment   */
    /* Define value to help with distribution of work */
    int distri,leftover;
    /* matrix */
    double *a = malloc(sizeof(double) * n * n);
    // assert(a != NULL);
    /* first make the solution */
    double *xx = malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    // assert(xx != NULL);
    /* solution vector, pretend to be unknown */
    double *x = malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    // assert(x != NULL);
    /* make right hand side b = Ax */
    double *b = malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    // assert(b != NULL);
    int left=1; //Indicater of this thread whether or not used leftover jobs
    //Calculate jobs needs to be done by this thread

    /* Assign iteration vector*/
    double *my_iter_vec = malloc(sizeof(double) * distri * (n+1) );
    // assert(my_iter_vec != NULL); 

    /*root id do all the preprocessing*/
    if (id==root){
    int i, j;
    /* fill matrix elements */
    for (i=0; i< n; i++)
        for (j=0; j< n; j++){
        a[i*n+j] = 1.0 + rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0);
        }

    /*Solution */
    for (i=0; i< n; i++)
        xx[i] = 3.0+rand();             /* or anything you like */

    MatVec(n, a, xx, b);

    distri = n/(size-1); //jobs per thread (int value)
    leftover = n%(size-1); // left over job number


    /*  Preprocessing done  */
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        x[i] = 0.5;         
        }
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    commT_S=MPI_Wtick();
    
    MPI_Bcast(a, n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(b, n, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(x, n, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&distri, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&leftover, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (id <= leftover & id !=0)
    {
        distri++;
        left=0;
    }
    if (id!=root){
        for (int i = 0; i < distri; i++)
        {
            int cur_i;
            cur_i = (id-1)*distri+left*leftover+i;
            double inv;
            inv = 1.0 / a[cur_i*n+cur_i] ;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                
                if (cur_i==j)
                {
                    my_iter_vec[i*(n+1)+j] = 0.0;
                    continue;
                }
                my_iter_vec[i*(n+1)+j] = -a[cur_i*n+j]*inv; //i row j column
            }
            my_iter_vec[i*(n+1)+n]= b[cur_i]*inv;//constant term
            
        }
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    commT_E=MPI_Wtick();
    commT+=commT_E-commT_S;
    printf("\nTime Spent:%32g",commT_S);

    // MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // printf()

    MPI_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note you use MPI_Wtick() and not MPI_Wtime()

Comment: Recompile your program with -g -O0, have it generate a core file and see where it crashes with a debugger. You can also use valgrind to spot memory errors

Comment: This looks wrong in your MatVec routine: `for (j=0; j<= n; j++){`   
Don't you mean `j<n` ? This could be trashing memory ...